# Non-existent service "form.csrf_provider" in Symfony2 application

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I am trying configure HWIOauthBundle in my Symfony2 application with this [link](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697).

When I run `app/console cache:clear`, or `composer install` I get this message:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]   
  The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-  
  existent service "form.csrf_provider".
```

My security.yml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    restapi:  { password: secretpw, roles: [ 'ROLE_API' ] }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                login_path:        /login
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my_user_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            http_basic:
                realm: "Demo REST API (username: restapi, password: secretpw)"
            stateless:  true

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false

            remember_me:
                key: "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                path: /
                domain: ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I was looking for this error in network, but I can't find good solution for me.

Comment: What version of Symfony2 do you use?

Comment: Possible answer would be that form.csrf_provider is depracted and removed in Symfony 3. Use security.csrf.token_manager instead. The reason is HWIOauthBundle is not ready to Symfony 3.

Answer (score -1):

I can't look now to hwio bundle but looks like you doesn't have 'form.csrf_provider' provider regisrered like service. search in project if 'form.csrf_provider' exist.